# Sequential criterion for differentiability

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a sequential criterion for differentiability,just like there is one for continuity ?
If not then,why so ?

I'm studying undergraduate real analysis and haven't  really come across one.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f:A\longrightarrow \mathbb R \text{ is differentiable at }x_0\iff$$
$$\text{ for every sequence } \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset A \text{ such that } x_n\rightarrow x_0, \text{ the following limit exists: }$$
$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {f(x_n)-f(x_0)}{x_n-x_0}=f'(x_0)$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Dimitris. I suspected the answer to be this,but am a little surprised this wasn't mentioned in the text I was referenced("Introduction to Real Analysis" by Bartle and Sherbert