# To show a function is not differentiable by sequential criterion

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Define $$f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ by setting $$ f(x)= 
\begin{cases}
    0,& \text{if } x=\frac{1}{n} , n\in N \\
    x,              & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

The question is : Is $f$ differentiable at $0$??

Now $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(\frac{1}{n})-f(0)}{\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(\frac{1}{n})}{\frac{1}{n}}=0$$ where as $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(-\frac{1}{n})-f(0)}{-\frac{1}{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{f(-\frac{1}{n})}{-\frac{1}{n}}=1$$

What I am showing here is that the left hand derivative and the right hand derivative are not equal.
Can this be generalized as :  If  there exists two sequences $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ such that $\{x_n\} \to a$ and $\{y_n\} \to a$, $$f'(a)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{f(x_n)-f(a)}{x_n-a}\ne \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(y_n)-f(a)}{y_n-a}=f'(a)$$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $a$?? Does there exist a  sequential criteria which would show something as not differentiable?? Like we have in uniform Continuity??

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: The right-hand derivative doesn't exist. But the answer to "Can this be generalized ..." is "Yes, it can".

Comment: @DanielFischer  Does my method work?? I have shown that lhd and rhd are different for a particular choice of $h$

Comment: @DanielFischer  How can it be generalized??

Comment: "If there exist two sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ with $x_n\to a$ and $y_n\to a$ such that $\lim \frac{f(x_n)-f(a)}{x_n-a} \neq \lim \frac{f(y_n)-f(a)}{y_n-a}$, then $f$ is not differentiable at $a$."

Comment: so what I wrote was correct??

Comment: Except for "What I am showing here is that the left hand derivative and the right hand derivative are not equal." The right-hand derivative doesn't exist for this function. Take $z_n = \frac{1}{n+\pi}$ for example.

Comment: @DanielFischer.. Yeah got it .. Thank you

Comment: Some information here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387853/sequential-criterion-for-differentiability

Answer (score 1):

See what you have shown here is taking $F(x_n)=\frac{f(x_n)-f(a)}{x_n-a}$ and showing if $x_n \to a$ then $F(x_n) \to l$(finite)[if the limit exists]. which actually comes from the definition from the limit. So it can be generalized.